# Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal error

Tags: sql, vba

I've looked at a bunch of posts regarding this error, but can't find a solution to handle my issue. Here's what I'm facing:

```vb
Sub test()
    Initialize
    Query_Run "select distinct([key status]) from controls"
End Sub

Function Query_Run(qstring)
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Application.ODBCTimeout = 120
    rs.Open qstring, Cn, adOpenStatic
End Function
```

*Initialize* creates a new connection to the database.

*Query_Run* creates a new record set and runs the sql query to store whatever the query would return. However, it is giving me the error mentioned in the title.

I've used *Query_Run* in numerous other areas in the project and it still works, but anything new I write gets the error mentioned in the title. `[key status]` exists and isn't misspelled, same with controls. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: can you show us the table definition for `controls`?

Comment: And also, never wise to put spaces in a column name.

Comment: no new query i write works including queries of other tables. [key status] exists in controls and should be returning either 'key' or 'non-key'.

Comment: queries of other tables with column names with spaces in them?  Please show the table definition.

Comment: What RDBMS is this? Please tag as *controls* can be a reserved words. Also do not wrap items in `SELECT` with parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general approach to solving this issue. The error is indicating that either the table name or the column name does not exist. The `OpenSchema` method can be used to list the table names which do exist along with the column names in those tables.

This macro will output the details of all of the tables and columns in the database to a worksheet for you to examine. If the table name or column name has been mangled in some way then you should be able to detect this. If your connection is somehow not pointing to the correct database then this should hopefully also be apparent.

```vb
Sub outputTablesAndColumns()

' Assumes that a variable called `Cn` is in scope
' and that `Cn` refers to an open ADODB.Connection

' Extract the schema
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = Cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns)

' Output the field names and the results
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents

    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    .Cells.Columns.Autofit
End With

' Tidy up
rs.Close

End Sub
```